# Google Play Developer Console : Some stats are missing

Tags: console, google-play

I'm the owner of a Google Developer Account. With it, I can connect to Google Play's Developer console, which allows me to have statistics about my different apps.

There are two kinds of statistics available : total number of active installations, showed per day (evolution of overall active installs of the app) for devices/users, and other statistics such as daily installs, daily uninstalls, daily updates of the application. Which is more precise, and very interesting.

The developer console offers a few sorting options for this data. You can show it by Android Version, by Carrier, by Country... etc.

I have no problems with the total number of active installations, in the sorted charts and list, it displays every version/carrier/whatever for every day.

In fact I have issues with the "daily" type of statistics. For example, I know that my app wonderful_app has been downloaded like 400 times in the last 2 months, on 4 Android versions. Google can show me the active installs per version, so I know it (the number increased for every version during this timelapse).

BUT when I look at daily installs for the same period, all I can see are two Android versions. How can this be possible?

I have similar results for other sorting options (country, app version...) the daily stats always display only a few elements in the list, so there is data which I miss, and badly need for analytics purposes.

Anyone knows if it's a bug, or a "feature" I couldn't understand?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got an answer from Google, and even if it's not really a solution, I'll close this question because I'm going to have to deal with it.

They answered that the stats are not to be taken too precisely, since there are often missing information and a lack of coherence between series. This is due to the fact that the v2 of this service is recent, and it might get better someday.

Comment: Yeah, they never fix it. I could understand if they told me that it was showing less than the actual amount of installs. But in my case it shows a lot more installs than I get paid for.